# hiding the bottom controls bar in iPhone Safari browser

Tags: html, iphone, safari

is there any way to hide the bottom navigation bar on mobile devices? (Safari and Android browsers)? I don't want users to click 'back button' to go back to the previous page. Is that even doable? I read about Adding the page to Home Screen, but it was in 2012. Did anything change? Can I use HTML or javascript to hide this bar somehow without adding the page to home screen?

Answer (score 0):

For iPhone, simply use the meta tag in your header:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
```

Android would utilize some more advanced JavaScript since most people don't use the default Android browser.